# Return value from withing a setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using Google Maps Autocomplete to set the value of an input, and I use http://jqueryvalidation.org/ to validate the minimum length.  Problem is Google Maps Autocomplete (and any asynchronous plugin) takes a moment to populate the input as it needs to access the remote server, and the jQuery Validation Plugin validates before the value is populated.  For a demo, see http://jsbin.com/digiz/1.

Is it possible to delay the validation for a specific rule on a specific element?

If not, is it possible to create a new validation method which has a brief delay?  For instance, see below for my feeble attempt.  The first `console.log` displays only the entered characters before "clicking" a Google provided result, but the second displays the updated value, so I know I am on the right track (I hope!).  I have not, however, figured out how to return the validation condition from within the setTimeout function.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("minlengthDelay", function(value, element, params) {
    console.log(element.value);
    var t=this;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(element.value);
        return t.optional(element) || $.trim(element.value).length>=params;
        }, 100);
    }, jQuery.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."));
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please?

Comment: Ok, give me a moment.

Comment: Not possible, `setTimeout()` returns only its `id`, which is an integer, with which you can stop the timer. In your code the return value goes to the bit space...

Comment: @ShaikMahaboobBasha.  Sorry for the delay.  See http://jsbin.com/digiz/1/.  Enter a character or two, then click one of the results.

Comment: @Teemu.  Yes, I found that `return window.setTimeout(function(){};` would return the timer ID.  What if the `return` is in the function as I show it?  Other solutions?

Comment: @Teemu.  Always bit space?  No way to bring back with a callback or something?  Like jQuery ajax or something (obviously, it is not ajax, but how you send something to the server, and the server sends something back)?

Comment: @Teemu  So no way to accomplish my goal? :(

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to delay the validation for a specific rule on a specific element?

No, I don't think so. The jQuery validation plugin does not support asynchronous functions.

> I have not, however, figured out how to return the validation condition from within the setTimeout function.

This is impossible - you cannot `return` a value from an asynchronous callback. You would need to offer a callback or return a promise, but that would require support for this by the function accepting your validation callback.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. Can it be done by offering a callback or return a promise? What do you mean by this?  If I extend my own methog, will this meet your requirement that the function must be able to accept the validation plugin?

Comment: No, the validation plugin would need to offer an asynchronous callback to your validation function (which takes it as a parameter) - but it doesn't offer one. Validation cannot be done asynchronously with that jQuery plugin.

Comment: @Bergi would this be possible with an ajax call and the `remote` method?

Comment: @user51462 Given [`remote`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), it looks like the plugin does support asynchronous validation in general (I hope it doesn't do sjax), but this doesn't seem to be available through `addMethod`.

Comment: I see, I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638971/jquery-validate-delaying-validation-of-an-input) to the OP but can call `.valid()` on the input directly - would it be appropriate to wrap this in a `setTimeout`? I don't like the arbitrariness of `setTimeout` though and it only works for the first validation of the input. If you have the time, I would really appreciate your input on my post.